# Argument cannot be null error in LWC when logging in to a Site

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce1-app, auth

[image]

HTML:

```
<template>

  <lightning-card class="slds-var-p-around_medium">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">

      <!--Logo/baranding-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <p class="fontSizeCustom">Sign in </p>
      </div>

      <!--Input Types-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="text" variant="standard" name="name" label="Username" placeholder="Enter Username"
          onchange={handleUsername} value={email}></lightning-input>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="password" variant="standard" name="name" label="Password" placeholder="Enter Password"
          onchange={handlePassword} value={password}></lightning-input>
      </div>

      <!--Login Button-->
      <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="button" onclick={handleLogin}>Log In</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </lightning-card>

  <!--error alert-->
  <template if:true={isError}>
    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-alert_error" role="alert">
      <span class="slds-assistive-text">error</span>
      <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-error slds-m-right_x-small"
        title="Description of icon when needed">
        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#error"></use>
        </svg>
      </span>
      {errorMessage}
      <div class="slds-notify__close">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-small slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">
          <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

</template>
```

JS:

```
import Email from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import login from '@salesforce/apex/LoginUser.login';
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class NitronsolarLogin extends LightningElement {

  email;
  password;
  isError=false;
  errorMessage;
  
  handleUsername(event){
    this.email=event.target.value;
  }
  
  handlePassword(event){
    this.password=event.target.value;
  }
  
  handleLogin(){
    console.log("Inside Login");
    console.log("Email Value: ", this.email);
    console.log('Password Value: ', this.password);

    if(this.email!=null && this.password!=null){
        login({username:this.email, password:this.password})
        .then((result)=> {
          this.isError = false;
          console.log('Result is: ', result)
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          console.log('Error is', error)
          this.isError=true;
          this.errorMessage = error.body.message;
        })
    }
  }
}
```

APEX:

```
global class LoginUser {
    @AuraEnabled
    global static String login(String userName, String password){
       String homeURL = 'https://empathetic-badger-32busx-dev-ed.trailblaze.my.site.com/nitronSolar/s/';
       ApexPages.PageReference pagrRef = Site.login(username,password, homeURL);
        return pagrRef.getURL();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the logs in the Developer Console to find out which line the error is occurring on? And I would suggest adding some System.debug lines to help.

Comment: The code has no erros on the developer console i have edited and updated the question to show this

Comment: To see errors when the code is running, you can open the Developer Console and any logs will appear under the log tab. That will show you the line number of any errors.

Comment: You also a SOQL error in your Apex, so you should fix that first since it is very clear.

Comment: @OgunseyinMagnus did changing the case fix your problem?

Comment: @fred yes the case change fixes the problem.

Comment: @OgunseyinMagnus good to hear! would you mind marking my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex is not case-sensitive, except when calling an `AuraEnabled` method from a Lightning Component, which is what you are doing here.

In the Apex controller you have `userName` but in the Javascript you have `username`. They have to be the same in both the Javascript and in the Apex.

It's best practice to use consistent cases in Apex anyway, so you avoid these kinds of errors.